# ExtJS:Load mask for only grid is not happening

Tags: extjs

I want to mask only my grid component, when the data is getting loaded. But on load mask , the whole window gets masked.Please suggest the necessary changes to achieve this behavior.
You can access the code in the below fiddle path, provided.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fti

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

You can call `grid.setLoading(true)` or `grid.setLoading('Custom Message')` if you have a reference to the grid.

[Link to Doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-setLoading)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var gridPanel = new Ext.grid.Panel({
            ...
            viewConfig: {
                loadMask: true
            },
            ...
});
```

Hope that helps.